# Making discord bot with Python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Making a mention message for discord bot

```
   @client.event
async def ze_message(msg):
    bot = f'<@{client.user.id}>'
          if message.content == bot:

    await message.channel.send("If you need any help type .help")
```

and this is what it says

```
       if message.content == bot:
IndentationError: unexpected indent`
```

Comment: Your indentation is completely wrong. Your `@client.event` should be at the very beginning not indented, your if statement, should also be inline with your bot variable initialization

Comment: then it says that `NameError: name 'bot' is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

Imports should be without indent.

Tip: Get a good IDE such as pycharm and or vscode.
These tools will give you much more feedback.

Comment: there are no imports in the example code and this is not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to write your code the way you should:

```
@client.event
async def ze_message(msg):
    bot = f'<@{client.user.id}>'
        if message.content == bot:
            await message.channel.send("If you need any help type .help")
```

After ":" the following code needs 4 more spaces then before.

And also **do not confuse intents with indents**

But I think there are more problems with your code than just the indents.

e.g. Did you mean to write`async def ze_message(msg):` if you want to use discords function you might want to call it `async def on_message(msg):` ...